# Drag And Drop using javascript

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop

i have to display google images in my website. i would like to add google images in my wishlist simply drag the image into dropbox. it will add into my wishlist. for this i am using this code. this code is from [mozilla](http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/DnD/.)

but it is not working in IE,CROME. is there any chance to compatible. otherwise is there any another chance to solve this problem?

actually i was used ninja drag-drop image code also. but it is not working properly for google images which displayed in my website.

actually i am displaying google images using  google api in my website. in my web page at below of this google results there is a dropbox which is like in the above url([mozilla](http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/DnD/.)). if i would like to add any image from the google results simply i have to drag the google image into dropbox.

Comment: That link is working fine in Chrom7 for me. Also, if you've seen this: http://www.thecssninja.com/javascript/drag-and-drop-upload Can you say what the problem really is?

Comment: thanks for your reply. actually i am doing this http://www.athensys.net/8003/mozilla/. search images from google and select any image and drop into this box. it is working fine in firefox but not in IE. actually this is not ninja code. i got this code from http://demos.hacks.mozilla.org/openweb/DnD/

Comment: is there any chance to do this using cssninja. but i tried a lot using ninja code but in ninja code there is an images have individual <div> for each. but here i am getting all google images in one <div> only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  function drop(evt) {
        evt.stopPropagation();
        evt.preventDefault(); 
        var imageUrl = evt.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');

        var rex = /src="?([^"\s]+)"?\s*/;
        var url, res;

        url = rex.exec(imageUrl);

        var dropped=document.getElementById('dropped');

        var img = document.createElement('img');
        img.setAttribute('src',url[1]);
        dropped.appendChild(img);
}
```

[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4E92W/29/)